# python spider how to get the input radio's value

Tags: python, jquery, radio-button, elementtree

the part of the html is:

```html
<p class="more">
    <span>S</span><br />
    <input type="radio" name="rt0" value="0/0/S" onclick='showEI(this,"0", "0", "","S")'/>
    ￥1140<br />
    <span class="seatNum">>9</span>
</p>
```

---

then i got the xpath of `￥1140`:

```
price = etree_html.find('.//*[@id="result_table"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[8]/text')
// print price
```

### the resurl is None

what can i do for this situation?

Comment: What do you want ? Get the value of the radio button (which is "0/0/S"), or the value written after it.

Do you want to get the value after posting a form, or from the raw HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

the part of html is:

```
<p class="more">
    <span>S</span><br />
    <input type="radio" name="rt0" value="0/0/S" onclick='showEI(this,"0", "0", "","S")'/>
    ￥1140<br />
    <span class="seatNum">>9</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html = """<p class="more">
    <span>S</span><br />
    <input type="radio" name="rt0" value="0/0/S" onclick='showEI(this,"0", "0", "","S")'/>
    ￥1140<br />
    <span class="seatNum">>9</span>
</p>"""
import re
pattern = re.compile('<input type="radio" name="rt0".*?/>(.*?)<br />', re.DOTALL)
price = pattern.findall(html)[0].strip() #the strip command is for clearing '\n' characters and whitespaces...
print price
```

It works...

Comment: thanks, I want use etree get the Radio buttons's value. can etree get it?

Comment: I don't know about etree but I think it can get according to this link: http://lxml.de/parsing.html